# Update the string that has already been printed every second in NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, system-calls

I am completely new to the assembly thing and googling for several hours and searching on SO didn't clear things out so I came to ask here.

What I want to achieve:

`[first second]: hello (stays on the screen for 1 second)`

`` [second second]: world (hello disappeared and now we have `world` in place of it) ``

And this flow is in an infinite loop

In other words, I want my terminal's stdout to flicker(change) between hello and world without appending any newlines, writing strings or any other things, I just want the existing, already printed text to be replaced with some another text.

I have written the infinite loop that will print `hello`, then wait for a second, then print `world`, and wait for a second. I have also put this code in an infinite loop.

Here is the code I have as of now:

```
section .data
    hello db "hello",10,0
    world db "world",10,0
    delay dq 1,0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, hello
    mov rdx, 6
    syscall

    mov rax, 35
    mov rdi, delay
    mov rsi, 0
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, world
    mov rdx, 6
    syscall

    mov rax, 35
    mov rdi, delay
    mov rsi, 0
    syscall

    call _start
```

Note that I use elf64 asm format and it is highly appreciated to suggest a solution in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print a `\r` carriage return (ASCII code 13) to put the cursor at the beginning of the line *without* scrolling the terminal the way `\n` line feed (ASCII 10) does.

Then you can overwrite the last thing you wrote.  If it's shorter, you can print spaces after your visible characters to "erase" the later characters still there.

e.g. since both words are the same length you could do this:

```
section .rodata
    hello db 13, "hello"        ; `\rhello`
    hello_len equ $ - hello
    world db 13, "world"
    world_len equ $ - world
```

Notice that `, 0` is not needed in your data because you're passing these buffers to `write` not `printf`, so they don't need to be `0`-terminated implicit-length C strings.  You also don't need to hard-code `mov rdx, 6`, you can use `mov rdx, hello_len` with the assembler calculating that for you.

---

For the sleeping part, you can use the `sleep` libc function, but for raw system calls you'll have to use [`nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).  (Like you're already doing.)

---

For the looping, don't use `call _start`; use `jmp`.  You don't want to push a return address; that would eventually stack overflow (after about 1 million seconds: 8MiB stack size limit and call pushes an 8-byte return address.)

Comment: `mov rax, 1
 mov rdi, 1
 mov rsi, 13h
 mov rdx, 6
 syscall`
using this haven't put my cursor to the beginning of the line. I also tried using glibc printf function but had an error on linking stage.

Comment: @Andrewf0s3Kosenko: `write` takes a *pointer* in RSI, not a single character value.  Also, ASCII CR is `13` (`0x0d`) not `13h`.  Updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using helpful guidance of Peter Cordes.

The working code looks like this:

```
section .data
    hello db "hello",13,0
    world db "world",13,0
    delay dq 1,0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, hello
    mov rdx, 6
    syscall

    mov rax, 35
    mov rdi, delay
    mov rsi, 0
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, world
    mov rdx, 6
    syscall

    mov rax, 35
    mov rdi, delay
    mov rsi, 0
    syscall

    jmp _start
```